# How to set tint for an image view programmatically in android?

Tags: android, imageview, tint

Need to set tint for an image view... I am using it the following way:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(R.color.blue,android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

But it doesn't change...

Comment: You may have used the integer resource id instead of integer color value, try to convert R.color.blue to getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)

Comment: Drawable drawable = ... ;
drawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.DST);   
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable); // any color can be used here

Answer (score 1265, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
@ADev has newer solution in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45571812/7399050), but his solution requires newer support library - 25.4.0 or above.

---

You can change the tint, quite easily in code via:

`imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));` // White Tint

If you want color tint then

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.COLOR_YOUR_COLOR), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

For Vector Drawable

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.COLOR_YOUR_COLOR), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: More Information: [public final void setColorFilter (int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter%28int%2C%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode%29)

Comment: In xml, android:tint="@color/blue"

Comment: android:tint="@color/blue" does not work while loading image via Glide.

Comment: i am using this code but it takin lot of time to set the color on image

Comment: Plus android:tint is 21+

Comment: `android:tint` works on all android versions. Maybe you're talking about `drawableTint`?

Comment: @finstas  the question was how to set tint programmatically not from xml. Read more: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)

Comment: @Hardik sorry, the reply was intended for user3175580's reply where he was talking about the xml-part

Comment: PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY doesn't work in my situation i used PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN and it works

Comment: The same situation to @mohnage7. PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY doesn't work for vector drawable in Android 8 for me, but PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN works.

Comment: The same situation to @mohnage7. PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY doesn't work for vector drawable in Android 6.0.1 MXB48T for me, but PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN works.

Comment: I faced with an interesting problem. Although I am using the methods described above, it does not work on Samsung Note 3 device. Then I figure out an interesting case : When initial tint color is given from xml, it cannot be changed dynamically with these methods. Solution is quite simple, I just  remove tint attribute from xml and set initial tint color also dynamically and cheers.. Hope this saves a few minutes for others :)

Comment: Was trying to tint an `ImageButton` which had png image in it with `DrawableCompat.setTint(v.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.gold));` which didn't work on API 19, but this did: `v.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.gold), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);`

Comment: Your update should have referenced my answer since that's where you got it from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45571812/7399050

Comment: @ADev of course but you haven't mention it properly in your answer that your solution is new and require newer support library 25.4.0 and above because with lower version of support lib this class is not available so no one could find it !!!! by the way i edited the answer :) good day...

Comment: it works perfectly fine except for Data Binding + Lenovo A7000-a + VectorDrawable T_T

Comment: ImageView imageViewIcon = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);
imageViewIcon.setColorFilter(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

Comment: This method does not work if the tint is set via XML. Remove tint from XML and set via this method programmatically.

Answer (score 405):

Most answers refer to using `setColorFilter` which is not what was originally asked.

The user @Tad has [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27929217/7399050) in the right direction but it only works on API 21+.

To set the tint on all Android versions, use the `ImageViewCompat`:

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView, ColorStateList.valueOf(yourTint));
```

Note that `yourTint` in this case must be a "color int". If you have a color resource like `R.color.blue`, you need to load the color int first:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue);
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Note that it works only on xml `ImageView` instances with AppCompat theme or on `AppCompatImageView` subclasses.

Comment: @ADev appreciate your solution but the question was asked in 2013 and ImageViewCompat and AppCompatImageView release with v4 support lib 25.4.0 in June 2017 and 25.1.0 December 2016 respectively :)

Comment: @ADev of course but you haven't mention it properly in your answer that your solution is new and require newer support library 25.4.0 and above because with lower version of support lib this class is not available so no one could find it !!!! by the way i edited the answer :) good day...

Answer (score 79):

This worked for me

```
mImageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.green_500));
```

Comment: yeah, worked for me too, without the second parameter.. it also can goes `mImageView.setColorFilter(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.green_500));`

Comment: upvoted and without the second parameter, it works like charm. Thx @toobsco42

Answer (score 39):

@Hardik has it right. The other error in your code is when you reference your XML-defined color. You passed only the id to the `setColorFilter` method, when you should use the ID to locate the color resource, and pass the *resource* to the `setColorFilter` method. Rewriting your original code below.

**If this line is within your activity:**

```
imageView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

**Else, you need to reference your main activity:**

```
Activity main = ...
imageView.setColorFilter(main.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Note that this is also true of the other types of resources, such as integers, bools, dimensions, etc. Except for string, for which you can directly use `getString()` in your Activity without the need to first call `getResources()` (don't ask me why).

Otherwise, your code looks good. (Though I haven't investigated the `setColorFilter` method too much...)

Answer (score 33):

Better simplified extension function thanks to [ADev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45571812/6478047)

```
fun ImageView.setTint(@ColorRes colorRes: Int) {
    ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(this, ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes)))
}
```

**Usage:-**

```
imageView.setTint(R.color.tintColor)
```

Comment: Is there a similar one for the Button's/TextView's text tint?

Comment: do you mean textview text color or  tint for textview drawable ?

Comment: I mean "text tint". The color of the text. But I think it's quite problematic, as text has a color for each state... Then again, how come it works fine for when I set accent color ... Odd.... Is it possible perhaps to set the accent color to a specific Button (or TextView)  , programmatically ?

Answer (score 25):

After i tried all methods and they did not work for me.

I get the solution by using another PortDuff.MODE.

```
imgEstadoBillete.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green),PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 25):

If your color has hex transparency, use the below code.

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintMode(imageView, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView, ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#80000000")));
```

To clear the tint

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView, null);
```

Comment: what is "img"'s type

Comment: @Beyaz `img` is of type ImageView.

Answer (score 17):

Simple and one line

```
imageView.setColorFilter(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
```

Answer (score 16):

Beginning with Lollipop, there is also a [tint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#setTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) method for BitmapDrawables that works with the new Palette class:

> public void setTintList (ColorStateList tint)

and

> public void setTintMode (PorterDuff.Mode tintMode)

On older versions of Android, you can now use the [DrawableCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html) library

Comment: actually, the support library does support it. see my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34479043/878126

Answer (score 14):

Try this. It should work on all Android versions that the support library supports:

```
public static Drawable getTintedDrawableOfColorResId(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Bitmap inputBitmap, @ColorRes int colorResId) {
    return getTintedDrawable(context, new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), inputBitmap), ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorResId));
}

public static Drawable getTintedDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Bitmap inputBitmap, @ColorInt int color) {
    return getTintedDrawable(context, new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), inputBitmap), color);
}

public static Drawable getTintedDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Drawable inputDrawable, @ColorInt int color) {
    Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(inputDrawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, color);
    DrawableCompat.setTintMode(wrapDrawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    return wrapDrawable;
}
```

You can use any of the above to make it work.

You can read about more interesting features of DrawableCompat on the docs, [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html).

Comment: I also had to do `imageView.getBackground()` to get the drawable, because `imageView.getDrawable()` was returning null.

Comment: @RockLee be sure that you used src in image view xml or setImageResource in code

Comment: this is the perfect way to set tint color for imageview background

Answer (score 14):

Kotlin solution using extension function, to set and unset the tinting :

```
fun ImageView.setTint(@ColorInt color: Int?) {
    if (color == null) {
        ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(this, null)
        return
    }
    ImageViewCompat.setImageTintMode(this, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(this, ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I found that we can use color selector for tint attr:

```
mImageView.setEnabled(true);
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrowup"
    android:tint="@color/section_arrowup_color" />
```

**section_arrowup_color.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Hi, It's not working for vector drawables..Any workaround for same?

Comment: @Manukumar Use `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src` , and add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` into the `defaultConfig` part of your build.gradle file. Tested to work fine on Kitkat emulator.

Comment: As per [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource), I've created a subdirectory _color_ in the _res_ directory to store the file section_arrowup_color.xml. Android Studio will help you create new files if you right click on the _color_ subdirectory, select _new_ and then _Color Resource File_.

Answer (score 13):

For set tint for an image view programmatically in android

I have two methods for android :

1)

```
imgView.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

2)

```
 DrawableCompat.setTint(imgView.getDrawable(),
                     ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue));
```

I hope I helped anyone out :-)

Answer (score 10):

As the first answer didn't work for me:

```
//get ImageView
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

//colorid is the id of a color defined in values/colors.xml
myImageView.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorid)));
```

This only seems to work in API 21+, but for me that wasn't an issue. You can use an ImageViewCompat to resolve that issue, tho.

I hope I helped anyone out :-)

Answer (score 10):

Adding to [ADev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7399050/adev)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45571812/5096103) (which in my opinion is the most correct), since the widespread adoption of Kotlin, and its useful extension functions:

```
fun ImageView.setTint(context: Context, @ColorRes colorId: Int) {
    val color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorId)
    val colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color)
    ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(this, colorStateList)
}
```

I think this is a function which could be useful to have in any Android project!

Answer (score 10):

An **extension** function in **kotlin**, to set and unset the tinting.

```
fun ImageView.setTint(@ColorRes color: Int?) {
  if (color == null) {
    ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(this, null)
  } else {
    ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(this, ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color)))
}}
```

Usage: `yourImageView.setTint(R.color.white)` for setting and for removing just: `yourImageView.setTint(null)`

Answer (score 8):

Beginning in Lollipop, there is a method called [`ImageView#setImageTintList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) that you can use... the advantage being that it takes a `ColorStateList` as opposed to just a single color, thus making the image's tint state-aware.

On pre-Lollipop devices, you can get the same behavior by tinting the drawable and then setting it as the `ImageView`'s image drawable:

```
ColorStateList csl = AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(context, R.color.my_clr_selector);
Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(imageView.getDrawable());
DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable, csl);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Random random=new Random;
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ColorFilter cf = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.rgb(random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255)),Mode.OVERLAY);

imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bg_box);
imageView.setColorFilter(cf);
```

Answer (score 4):

In java I'm using

```
imageView.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)));
```

Answer (score 3):

As @milosmns said, you should use

`imageView.setColorFilter(getResouces().getColor(R.color.blue),android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);`

This API need color value instead of color resource id, That's the root cause why your statement didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `PoterDuff.Mode`,
Use `setColorFilter()` it works for all.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setColorFilter(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.msg_read));
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to set selector to your tint:

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(iv, getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.app_icon_click_color));
```

Answer (score 2):

I am late in the party but I didn't see my solusion above. We are able to set tint color via `setImageResource()`, too (my minSdkVersion is 24).

So, first, you need to create a selector and save it in `/drawable` asset folder (I call it `ic_color_white_green_search.xml`)

```
<!-- Focused and not pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_pressed="false">

    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:tint="@color/branding_green"/>
</item>

<!-- Focused and pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_pressed="true">

    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:tint="@color/branding_green"/>
</item>

<!-- Default -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_search"/>
```

Then set it in code like this:

```
val icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon) as ImageButton
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_color_white_green_search)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this code works. I use it with card and image views but i thins it works in any view to change their tints colors.
cardBookmark is my cardView.

```
var cardDrawable: Drawable = binding.cardBookmark.background
cardDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(cardDrawable)
DrawableCompat.setTint(cardDrawable, resources.getColor(R.color.shuffleColor))
binding.cardBookmark.background = cardDrawable
```

Answer (score 2):

I did below:

```
view.drawable.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.color_05F73F))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This is not the answer for this post. But it is the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205042/remove-tint-color-programmatically-in-android) question i.e. how to reset the color/tint of the drawable or imageview. Sorry, for putting this over here as that question is not accepting answers and referring to this post for answers. So, adding it here so that someone looking for a solution might look end up at this.

As mentioned by [@RRGT19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10977224/rrgt19) in the comment of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45205601/12344308) answer. We can reset the color using `setImageTintList()` and passing `null` as the tintList. It worked magically for me.

```kotlin
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are changing tint on Focus change then try this please

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(imgView.getDrawable(),
                 ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue));
```

Answer (score 0):

After I tried all methods and they did not work for me.

I get the solution specially in case if you are changing the color through any colorPicker library which returns an Integer value of selectedColor.

`widgetIcon` is my ImageView and `selectedColor` is the color from colorPicker

```
var imageDrawable: Drawable = widgetIcon.background
        imageDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(imageDrawable)
        DrawableCompat.setTint(imageDrawable, selectedColor)
        widgetIcon.background = imageDrawable
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                menuIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary)));
            }
```

I use this piece of code to change the tint of my menuIcon hope this helps.

Answer (score -4):

Not exact answer but a simpler alternative:

- Place another view on top of the image
- Change the **alpha** value of the view however you want (programmatically) to get the desired effect.

Here is a snippet for that:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height120"
        android:contentDescription="@string/my_description"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/my_awesome_image"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height120"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/my_blue_color"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: this is about tint! not alpha that is for transparency.

Comment: But that ends up acting as a tint. You should try it yourself. This is just one way to look at things.

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary I know this is late but what if the image is `png`. Then won't the background change? Also Alpha and tint are very different. Tint Is like color replacement, if I am not wrong. No offence intended. Just trying to help :)

Comment: Valid point. This answer helped in my case. Hope fits someone else's shoes too.