# How to get tint color from ImageView via code

Tags: android

How to **get** `android:tint=""` color from [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) via code?

Comment: I think `setImageTintList()` is what you want : [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList))

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20121975/423980)

Comment: @mt0s not to **set**, but to **get**

Comment: Right, I missed the get. Then `getColorFilter()` should work for you

Comment: @mt0s I don't know how to get the color from ColorFilter object.

Comment: Does `getImageTintList()` not work for ya? It'll return a `ColorStateList`, but you can just call `getDefaultColor()` on that.

Comment: @MikeM. "call requires api 23" for `getImageTintList`. Weird since tint is appcompat.

Comment: Yeah, I thought you were dealing with API>=23, since you specified a straight `ImageView`. Anyhoo, the `tint` attribute does work with `AppCompatImageView`, but I can't find any simple way of getting it after it's set. They probably omitted `getImageTintList()` in appcompat 'cause it's a convoluted mess of varying helper classes just to get it set correctly on all supported versions. I'll let ya know if I find anything.

Answer (score 9):

To get the tint on all Android versions, use the ImageViewCompat:

```
int color = ImageViewCompat.getImageTintList(yourImageView).getDefaultColor();
```