# Android - Draw a ribbon shape

Tags: android, shapes, ribbon

I am trying not to use image view. This is because, later, I will generate many objects with the same shape but different colors, so I wouldn't need to keep adding image views but simply adding colors on my code.

[image]

How can I create those images on Android Studio? I looked over Paint, onDraw, Canvas, etc, but this looks difficult to me.

Comment: Take one white triangle image, keep it on left, and change the background of the rest view as you need

Comment: there are many ways to do this, but best way would probably be to use vector drawable

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Use a 9 patch or a VectorDrawable.

Comment: how to do that from top to bottom, it is from right to left, how can we do it from top to bottom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use from XML , Try this way it will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="#5EB888" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item
        android:top="-26dp"
        android:bottom="31dp"
        android:left="-90dp"
        android:right="75dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>



</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: is that possible to remove that white color?

Comment: The second rectangle you have given white color that one..i tried to with transparent...but that time it will look like rectangle

Comment: keep it white please

Comment: Ya i understood what u done..even its great work only..but sometime the background will like image..that time we can't give set this white color tha'ts why i asked

Comment: did you try with same color?

Comment: ya..that time its working...am asking about when the background as image then we cant set this color code na?so we have to give transparent one.

Answer (score 1):

You can create vector image using any vector program like Adobe Illustrator or convert it using a conversion tool like [vectormagic](https://vectormagic.com/) or find already existing one then import it to android studio.

[image]

it will be imported as xml file where you can change the colors as you want

Answer (score 1):

Create a drawable file as named left_arrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="1%" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#00000000" />

            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Now, create a view layout to create this type of stripes or image like this, here is the below code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/left_arrow"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9" />
```

This above layout creates the required arrow stripe as a layout.

Now add this layout to your required layout where you wan't to show this stripes. For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include 
android:id="@+id/llMain"
layout="@layout/xtra"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, you are able to also use OnClickListener by using "llMain".
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the white png image you already have and use the [setColorFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20121975/4944007) method on the image view class to tint it with any color you desire