# Remove Tint Color Programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I want to **programmatically** remove (reset) my ImageView **Tint color** which was already set in XML layout.

Comment: try `imageview.setColorFilter(null);`

Comment: This question is NOT A DUPLICATE of the linked question and does not have an answer there (at the time of writing this comment).

Comment: In older APIs you can use: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ImageViewCompat#setimagetintlist passing null as the tintList

Answer (score 61):

I think if above things doesn't works, you can try adding the image again to the imageview programatically, while adding it again programatically don't set tintcolor for it, it will be inflated with the original color

```
    myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourDrwable);
```

or I think this should work for you.

```
    imageview.setColorFilter(null)
```

or

```
    imageView.clearColorFilter()
```

or

```
    imageView.drawable.setTintList(null)
```

or

```
    ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView, null);
```

updated based on the comments

Comment: `imageView.clearColorFilter()`

Comment: `imageView.setBackgroundTintList(null)`

Comment: `imageView.drawable.setTintList(null)` to clear the tint. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#setTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)): `Color state list to use for tinting this drawable, or null to clear the tint This value may be null.`

Comment: I had used  app:tint= in xml and clearColorFilter and colorFilter = null didn't work. But .drawable.setTintList(null) worked if it was done after the drawable had been set to the ImageView.

Comment: `ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView, null);` works for me.

Comment: @RRGT19 thanks! using ImageViewCompat is the only way that works for me

Comment: `imageView.setImageTintList(null)` worked for me.

Comment: for me I had to do both clearColorFilter() and drawable.setTintList(null)

Comment: ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(ivImage, null);
only last one works for me.