# ImageView remove tint color?

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, tint

Before I decided to ask it, I search some [Remove Tint Color Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205042/remove-tint-color-programmatically-in-android), but it marked as duplicate so I didn't know if this is also a duplicate or not? because it didn't answer my question, I think.

Because I am asking also if is it possible to **RESET** or **REMOVE** the tint of `ImageView` after changing the `drawable`.

This is the normal image

[image]

This is the selected image

[image]

and this is the normal image again after deselecting the image

[image]

and this is my code.

```
if (isSelected) {
    // Reset the ImageView to normal
    isSelected = false
    imgHeart.setImageDrawable(itemView.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_border_24))
} else {
    // Tint ImageView to Red
    isSelected = true
    imgHeart.setImageDrawable(itemView.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_24))
    imgHeart.imageTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.colorRedHeart))
}
```

I also try the `imgHeart.imageTintList = null` but the image is turning into white or disappear.
I also try the `imgHeart.colorFilter = null` but the image is do nothing and turning into the last image.

I am using the [Material Design Icon](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=favorite&style=baseline).

What I want to bring back the image into normal **`drawable`** as you see in the first image.

Thank you.

Comment: I tried the code and call `imgHeart.imageTintList = null` after `imgHeart.setImageDrawable` exactly cleared the tint, I think there must be some problems elsewhere.

Comment: Do you need all 3 icons, or only the last 2?

Answer (score 0):

The selected drawable is a completely different drawable than the other 2. You can't tint `baseline_favorite_border_24` to look like the selected one, you can tint only the borders and can't fill it with color. By the way `imageTintList` requires `API 21+`.  
So use 2 drawables(you don't need to download them, they exist in Android Studio), name the selected one as `baseline_favorite_filled_24` and toggle between them.

```
if (isSelected) {
    isSelected = false
    imgHeart.setImageDrawable(itemView.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_border_24))
} else {
    isSelected = true
    imgHeart.setImageDrawable(itemView.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_filled_24))
}
```