# How to programmatically change tint color of imageView?

Tags: android

```
 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/star_icon"
      android:id="+@starid"/>
```

I need to change tint color of icon programmatically help me

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121938/how-to-set-tint-for-an-image-view-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Thanks bro it's worked ..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks for Hardik, [orginal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20121975/4380127)

You can change the tint, quite easily in code via:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
```

If you want color tint then:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context,
R.color.COLOR_YOUR_COLOR));
```

with mode:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context,
R.color.COLOR_YOUR_COLOR), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

in my case:

```
imgBottomDivider.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),
            mPreferences.isNightMode() ? R.color.colorWhite : R.color.colorBlack));
```

[image: in night mode]
[image: in day mode]

Answer (score 6):

use

```
imageView.setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)
```

or

```
imageView.setColorFilter(int color)
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter(int)

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
imageViewDone.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourcolor), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Color Filter

```
  imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.CHOICE_COLOUR), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use default Duff mode for the imagevview you can prefer to

```
imageView.setColorFilter(int color)
```

but if you want to change the colour duff like light to multiple or dark then you should use:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)
```