# setBackgroundTintList for button programmatically with a hex value / ColorDrawable

Tags: android, android-button, colordrawable

I'm trying to set the background tint of a button programmatically, not to a color resource as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121938/how-to-set-tint-for-an-image-view-programmatically-in-android#20121975), but instead to a hex value.  At the moment, I have converted a hex value into a ColorDrawable, but do not know how to use this to set the background tint with the `.setBackgroundTintList()` method of my button.  Note that this is being done in a Fragment and the context is stored in a global variable called `mContext`.

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Comment: You can use like,  bLogin.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#DC143C"))); OR

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**on API +21**

```
btn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#buttonColor")));
```

**or Compat**

```
         Drawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("color"));
         // Wrap the drawable so that future tinting calls work
         // on pre-v21 devices. Always use the returned drawable.
        drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);


        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable,Color.parseColor("colorTint"));
           //or tint list  
       //DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable,ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
        btn.setBackground(drawable); //apply drwable with tint to the ctn
```

Comment: The second method doesn't crash on API <21 environments but is unfortunately equivalent to all the methods that replace the background - the styling disappears, there's no pressed state, etc.

Comment: **However** if you replace the first four lines with `Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(control.getBackground());` **it works!**

Answer (score 4):

Using Compat's static functions:

```
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(btn, ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")));
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is 2 way :**

**1) get the Color name from color.xml**

```
.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ResourcesCompat.getColor(
                        getResources(), R.color.your_color, null)));
```

**2) using hexadecimal Color String**

```
.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#color")));
```