# Android app widgets background shape change color opacity programmatically

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview, appwidgetprovider

I have developed an app widget with round corners. I've basically set a background drawable to the root of the app widget layout.

Now I'm trying to change its background opacity without losing round corners.

I know that `RemoteViews` are pretty limited.

Right now I'm using this code: `views.setInt(R.id.root_layout_widget, "setBackgroundColor", ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(Color.WHITE, opacity))`

But this way I lose rounded corners. If I wasn't using `RemoteViews` I would get the background of the element and set its alpha.

My root element is a LinearLayout and my background drawable is the following:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Do you know of any ways to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this I removed the background from my root LinearLayout and place the ShapeDrawable to an ImageView and rearranged my layout like this:

Before:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:background="@drawable/round_corners">
    .....
    .....
</LinearLayout>
```

After:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:src="@drawable/round_corners"/>
    <LinearLayout>
        .....
        .....
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And to change the background opacity without losing the round corners:

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.background, "setImageAlpha", alpha)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
int transparency = 192;(the amount of opacity level you want to give)

views.setInt(R.id.root_layout_widget, "setBackgroundColor", transparency);
```

in the place of

```
views.setInt(R.id.root_layout_widget, "setBackgroundColor", ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(Color.WHITE, opacity))
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. I edited the post if that can help.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the background colour you will replace your existing drawable, kind of annoying. I'd suggest looking into setting the tint colour on your background view, you might find this answer helpful:  [How to set tint for an image view programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121938/how-to-set-tint-for-an-image-view-programmatically-in-android)