# set background inside an image - android xml

Tags: java, android, xml

In my android app, I need to set background inside an image resource. On attempting to do that, the spaces around the image takes the background as well, but I want the image background to be only inside the image.

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pen"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                android:src="@drawable/pencil"
                android:background="#000"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/upcount"/>
```

I have tried to do it programmatically as well but getting the same result

```
pen.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 50));
```

this is sample of what I try to achieve. let the background be only on the pencil

[image]

Comment: share screenshot what you want and what you get

Comment: @ShivamKumar: have done that

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20121975/5110595)

Comment: so do you want the arrow to be in different color? or the background behind the arrow?

Comment: I think you want  black color image. Right?

Comment: This image you want or get

Comment: yes @JyotiJK I want black colored image

Comment: so see answer below

Comment: Then Remove  android:background="#000" . It will set background as black to imageview.  and it will not consider image source.  can you post @drawable/pencil

Comment: @drawable/pencil is the image posted in the question

Comment: I dont know why I got a downvote. is not a honet attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called tint in Android. You can use `android:tint` attribute. When you set tint on Image, then image color is changed.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Use [`AppCompatImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView) for better support of tint on older versions of Android.

You can set it programmatically by [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20121938/6891563)

> `imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));`

Comment: You got down-vote perhaps because your question was not clear. So please use always clear language and read question before posting, that your requirement is clear.