# How to change the color of an image drawn with Canvas?

Tags: android

I have a list of seat images drawn with canvas, and I want when I click on an image it will change color. Now it all changes color every time I click. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

**setUp** is a function used to set up the things needed to draw an image with Canvas

```
private void setUp() {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icons8_bus_36_border);
    tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
    if (bitmap == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setUp: null");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "setUp: not null");
    }
}
```

**sequentially** is the function I use to draw images with Canvas

```
 private void sequentially() {
    setUp();
    imageList = new HashMap<>();
    chooseColor = Color.parseColor("#1A86C8");
    seat.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams firstImg = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    firstImg.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams forRow = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    forRow.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 15);
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        row = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        row.setLayoutParams(forRow);
        seat.addView(row);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            countForImage++;
            imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
            imageList.put(countForImage, imageView);
            Log.d(TAG, "sequentially: number" + countForImage);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(firstImg);
            tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), tempBitmap));
            row.addView(imageView);
            if (i == 1 && j == 0) {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**loopSet** is the function I use to set the color change event

```
 public void loopSeat(Map<Integer, ImageView> map) {
    Log.d(TAG, "loopSeat: running");
    Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) pair.getValue();
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick at number= :" + pair.getKey());
                setColor(imageView);
            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG, "loopSeat: key= " + pair.getKey());
    }
}
```

**setColor** will be the function responsible for changing the color of the image

```
 public void setColor(ImageView imageView) {
   color,need to fix 
    Log.d(TAG, "setColor running");
    mPaint = new Paint(chooseColor);
    ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(chooseColor, 1);
    mPaint.setColorFilter(filter);
    Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, mPaint);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm));
}
```

Comment: Are you mean to say `onClick` not working ?

Comment: Ah no, I mean everything works but instead of just changing the image i click , it change all the image..

Comment: Why you are using canvas?

Comment: My boss want me do that, and my task like booking seat, i can not use a regular layout to do that.

Comment: use backgroundtint.

Comment: Why use both `drawbitmap` and `setimagedrawable` ?

Comment: It a dynamic layout bro, it change by the number of seat show up in the screen, and my boss obsess with Canvas, tell me that i have to use it. Maybe in the future my boss want to add a human image that seat on the chair  into that image, only Canvas can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Bitmap instance of the ImageView are the same. You need to copy to a new Bitmap for each ImageView:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean)

Though I'd recommend to use the tint property of ImageView:
[How to set tint for an image view programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121938/how-to-set-tint-for-an-image-view-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code in **setColor** function according to the suggestion of @Benoit. And it works perfect

```
public void setColor(ImageView imageView) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setColor: running");
    mPaint = new Paint(chooseColor);
    ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(chooseColor, 1);
    mPaint.setColorFilter(filter);
    //end of set color

   //start to creat a new bitmap
    Bitmap bm = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
    choosBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(choosBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), choosBitmap));
}
```

Comment: why use Bitmap.createBitmap ?

Comment: Use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` instead.

Comment: Ty for the advice, using the tint element is wat better, i dont know what Bitmap.creatBitmap mean, i just do the same with the guide post.