# How to modify the Lanucher Icons created by Image Asset Studio in Android Studio 3.4?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have read the artical https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio

I try to create  a Lanucher Icons  using the tool by *Right-click the res folder and select New > Image Asset*.

How can I modifty the Lanucher Icons I created by Image Asset Studio ?

BTW, If I choose *Right-click the res folder and select New > Image Asset*, the color in *Background Layer* will be reset, you can see the Image A.

**Image A**

[image: id]

Comment: When you create new it's override older. Did you try ?

Comment: what you want to modify in the icons?

Comment: I hope to modify to the color of Background Layer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20121975

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11376610